# How do i straighten UV island without warping them?

Tags: texturing, uv

i have those curly UV island witch can make them harder to work with.
how do i straighten up without warping them?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this video will help

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TZMg3nT229WVAF4RRS4pz20XnROdeJ7M/view?usp=sharing

This is the method I always use. If this doesn't work, you can try UV Squares add-on

Comment: your method is what i tried to use but its still getting warped, :/
i would consider the add on but as for now, i cannot do any universal parchases.
so i cant buy it for the time being so if there is any other way anybody is familiar with please let me know.